# Partner Communities Users Setup

Tags: partner-communities

The accounts in SFDC are to be setup as partner accounts using the new Partner Communities. Some of the contacts in these accounts would be created as users of the partner communities.

Now, it is required that some contacts (partner community users) should have access to multiple accounts. There are two use cases we are trying to address:

1) the partner community user is one of the executives across two partner accounts and needs access to information from both (both transactional records and reports)

2) another set of partner community users are admins who can manage users across different partner community accounts.

How do we achieve this?

Comment: Partner Users can own Accounts which are typically considered children of the Partner Account. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I edited my question a bit. I am wanting to know whether a partner community user allocated to multiple partner accounts?

Comment: A Partner User can only be directly associated with one account. But, if the other Accounts are created as children of his primary account, he'll have the permissions he needs to manage/administer the other accounts. Otherwise, you'd need to create separate User Accounts for him. He can also be the owner of other accounts whether they're under his or not. It all depends on how your configure your permissions.

Comment: Also I am not saying all users need to be given salesforce licence .Only those who need access to all accounts can be Salesforce license